# Ratpack 1.5.4 hystrix dependency cannot be resolved

Tags: maven, ratpack

I cannot compile my project that uses Ratpack 1.5.4 because there is a missing dependency to Hystrix 1.5.13 which cannot be resolved.

[http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A"com.netflix.hystrix"%20AND%20v%3A"1.5.13"](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3Acom.netflix.hystrix"%20AND%20v%3A"1.5.13)

What is wrong here?

Comment: What does your `build.gradle` file look like?

Comment: i dont use gradle, just maven. in the pom.xml i added ratpack, but version 1.5.4, which is the latest includes a dependency to hystrix 1.5.13 which is not on maven central and therefore the project does not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try excluding `com.netflix:hystrix-core:1.5.13` from `io.ratpack:ratpack-hystrix:1.5.4` and then you can add `com.netflix:hystrix-core:1.5.12` directly to your pom.xml file, something like that:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.ratpack</groupId>
            <artifactId>ratpack-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.ratpack</groupId>
            <artifactId>ratpack-hystrix</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.netflix.hystrix</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hystrix-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netflix.hystrix</groupId>
            <artifactId>hystrix-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I've tested this simple Maven Ratpack "Hello, World!" app https://github.com/wololock/ratpack-maven-example

It compiles in Travis without any issue - https://travis-ci.org/wololock/ratpack-maven-example (I have `com.netflix:hystrix-core:1.5.13` in my local .m2 repository, so I wanted to use something with a clean local Maven repository like Travis CI)

I don't know if version `1.5.13` got rolled back or something like that. It can be found in MvnRepository.com https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.netflix.hystrix/hystrix-core/1.5.13 however it says that 1.5.12 is newer, even though it got released 2 months earlier.